# How to create a Dynamic Scrollable Grid on tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, grid-layout, tkinter-canvas

When I say a dynamic grid I'm saying a grid that adjusts the number of columns(like bootstrap) according to the window width, so it must adjust the "cards" accordingly, and when I say scrollable... well... easier to understand.

I've tried 2 aproachs:

1. create a dynamic grid and then make it scrollable.
2. create a scrollable grid and then make it dynamic.

I've failed in both ways! I've found out that for being scrollable the grid can't be in a simple frame, it must be in a Canvas. And for the canvas I'm having a hard time making it dynamic.

Down here is my dynamic grid code

```
class DynaGrid(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.columns = None
        self.bind('<Configure>', self.re_grid)

    def re_grid(self, event=None):
        grid_width = self.winfo_width()
        slaves = self.grid_slaves()
        slaves_width = slaves[1].winfo_width()
        cols = grid_width // slaves_width
        if (cols == self.columns) | (cols == 0):  
            return
        for i, slave in enumerate(reversed(slaves)):
            slave.grid_forget()
            slave.grid(row=i // cols, column=i % cols)
        self.columns = cols

class CardFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, bd=1, relief=tk.RAISED, **kwargs)

        tk.Label(self, text="Hello").pack()
   
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    frame = DynaGrid(root)
    frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

CardFrame(frame).grid() 
CardFrame(frame).grid()
CardFrame(frame).grid() 
CardFrame(frame).grid()
CardFrame(frame).grid() 
CardFrame(frame).grid()
CardFrame(frame).grid() 
CardFrame(frame).grid()
root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I wont waste other people's time posting my messy canvas code here instead I've got one from
https://blog.tecladocode.com/tkinter-scrollable-frames/
which I've made the change to use my "cards" instead of labels.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class ScrollableFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(container, *args, **kwargs)
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
        self.scrollable_frame = ttk.Frame(canvas)

        self.scrollable_frame.bind(
            "<Configure>",
            lambda e: canvas.configure(
                scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")
            )
        )

        canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")

        canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

        canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

class TestFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, bd=5, relief=tk.RAISED, **kwargs)

        tk.Label(self, text="name").pack(pady=10)
  
root = tk.Tk()
frame = ScrollableFrame(root)

for i in range(50):

    TestFrame(frame.scrollable_frame).grid()

frame.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

To make the dynamic scrollable canvas the tricky part here is use the re_grid function inside the canvas. I'm lost in how I'll get the window width correctly like I did in the dynaGrid code.

In the end I want a mash up of these two codes; a Class that is some sort of  frame with dynamic grid with lateral scroll.

Comment: Please don't ask a question and then post someone else's code that isn't doing what your code is doing. Take the time to create a proper [mcve] for your question. Also, please post code that is syntactically correct. Your first block of code has indentation errors.

Comment: Do you literally want to create a grid with equal width columns, or is it good enough to just wrap the contents of a row when they don't fit?

Comment: ident fixed.. sorry.. yes my grid will have equal width columns.  in the production code it will be a property from conf classs

Comment: it doesnt work, this way  the scroll does not match the rows... the inverte way of you said  around the canvas becomes "a tile"

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the scroll does not match the rows". If you have a frame that behaves the way you want, you can simply add that frame to a canvas so that you can use the scrolling ability of the canvas.

Comment: i think I understood what you are saying... maybe i tried something different! i'll try what i think is your way and tell  if it works. tks

Comment: Bryan , it worked. thanks for the tip. it was not the way i had in mind to work with, but yeah it solves the issue! the problem that i had trying "your way" was that was not managing correctly the frames properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your canvas is a frame inside your class,
so, what you need to do is bind your re-grid function to your master frame and keep the scrollable frame config callback as it is. Then  alter the grid, inside your canvas, instead of your 'dynamic grid' from your re-grid function . Simple as that!
And I think it was easier to say: I want to create a window that behaves like a File Explorer

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class ScrollableFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def _init_(self, container, *args, **kwargs):
        super()._init_(container, *args, **kwargs)
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
        self.scrollable_frame = ttk.Frame(canvas)
        self.columns=0

        self.scrollable_frame.bind(
            "<Configure>",
            lambda e: canvas.configure(
                scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")
            )
        )

        self.bind('<Configure>', self.regrid)

        canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")

        canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

        canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

    def regrid(self, event=None):
        print(type(self))
        grid_width = self.winfo_width()
        slaves = self.scrollable_frame.grid_slaves()
        print(len(slaves))
        slaves_width = slaves[1].winfo_width()
        cols = grid_width // slaves_width
        if (cols == self.columns) | (cols == 0):  # if the column number has not changed, abort
            return
        for i, slave in enumerate(reversed(slaves)):
            slave.grid_forget()
            slave.grid(row=i // cols, column=i % cols)
        self.columns = cols

class TestFrame(tk.Frame):
    def _init_(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame._init_(self, master, bd=5, relief=tk.RAISED, **kwargs)

        tk.Label(self, text="name").pack(pady=10)
        tk.Label(self, text=" info ........ info ").pack(pady=10)


root = tk.Tk()
frame = ScrollableFrame(root)

for i in range(10):
    TestFrame(frame.scrollable_frame).grid()
    TestFrame(frame.scrollable_frame).grid()

frame.pack(side="left", fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```